# Api call using Retrofit in splash screen

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am quite new to android development, Now I have an application which
call quite big record from Rest Api using Retrofit and RxJava and save
it to local database during load splash screen. It take more than 5
minute to loading and finish splash screen, it's very annoying for
user experience. Does anyone have any ideas to call Rest Api at any
point before load splash screen? Some data which save in local
database are need on the main screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is implement a load more functionality , initially retrieve only few records which user can see at a time on whole screen and then Clicking on load more or scrolling down to end it should load next records. This on demand loading will be good option i guess.

Comment: In this situation data need to load all before start the main screen, but only a few data  use as a menu and other use on another page. So it could not a have load more functionality, and for now I just load a few data for main screen and another data just load in background, but I'm not quite sure if the process is still running when main screen start.